# Docker networking - producer cannot see Kafka

Tags: docker, networking, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Having trouble figuring out why my producer (from outside Docker) is not able to connect to Kafka in Docker.  Here's the docker compose

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'arm64v8/zookeeper:latest'
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - my_network

  kafka:
    image: 'wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.8.1'
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - '29092:29092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: false
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: 'events:1:1'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - my_network
```

I try to connect using brokers URL `localhost:29092` from the host machine.  I expect it to work because:

1. the kafka container exposes that port
2. the kafka listener includes `PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:29092`

However I get this error from my application:

> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9092: connect: connection refused

I tried running the kafka cli directly:

```bash
$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:29092 --topic events
```

No error.  But then when I try to produce a message, it doesn't work:

```bash
> Hi KAFKA!
WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node 1 (kafka/127.0.0.1:9092) 
could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this qualifies as an answer:

The old "turn it off and on again" worked here.  The config is fine; something else either in Docker or in the host networking wasn't working.  Seems to be working now so the settings appear to be fine.

Comment: Host networking? Did you modify /etc/hosts file? Because you shouldn't

Comment: @OneCricketeer I did not modify the hosts file; I still don't now why it wouldn't work